# Excel Python script for data management

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, data-management

I'm trying to write a python script to collect data from an [excel table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKNFR.png) (see picture) with a lot of spreadsheets and data in in.

The table contains mole fraction of species in each column at different pressure in each row.

I will need just tables named with "..._end_point_vs_parameter". PFRC1... represents mole fraction results at 100°C so i have to consider up to PFRC13_end_point_vs_parameter (700°C).

My script is currently working just for one row and one spreadsheet:

```
import pandas as pd


species = ["O2","CO","CO2","CH4","H2O","C2H6","CH2O","C2H4","CH3OH","C2H2","CH3COCH3","C3H8","C3H6","IC4H8","IC8H18"]
reactors = ["PFRC1","PFRC2","PFRC3","PFRC4","PFRC5","PFRC6","PFRC7","PFRC8","PFRC9","PFRC10", "PFRC11", "PFRC12", "PFRC13"]

xlsfile = pd.ExcelFile('PLUG_MehlPRF2011_1000sccm.xlsx')

sheets = xlsfile.sheet_names

frames = dict.fromkeys(sheets)

output =pd.DataFrame(index=reactors)



for sheet in sheets:
    df = xlsfile.parse(sheet_name=sheet)
    frames[sheet] = df

#for reactor in reactors:
#    [frame for key, frame in frames.items() if reactor in key]


for compound in species:
    profile=pd.Series(name=compound, index=reactors)
    for reactor in reactors:
        columname = " Mole_fraction_"+compound+"_"+reactor+"_()"
        for key in frames:
            df=frames[key]
            if columname in df.columns:
                profile[reactor]=df[columname].iloc[-1]    
    output[compound]=profile

output.to_excel("profiles.xlsx")
```

How can i collect data from different spreadsheads and for each defined column name all data in it. I need to somehow summarize those data into [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLrhI.png).